# Django: How to save a ID in a ManyToMany Relation in a form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i am testing nesting different models and how to populate them via a form in django.

(using Django 2.2 and PostgreSQL)

These are my models...

> models.py

```
class Guest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    meal = models.ManyToManyField('Meal')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Meal(models.Model):
    dish = models.ForeignKey('Dish', null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    table = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Dish:" "{}" "/ Table:" "{}".format(self.dish, self.table)


class Dish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

> views.py

```
class GuestCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Guest
    template_name ="testa/create_guest.html"
    form_class = GuestForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('testa:testa_home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

> forms.py

```
class GuestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    dish = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None)

    # --- Input for meal.table
    table_input = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Guest
        fields = [ 
            'name',
            'dish',
            'table_input'
            ]


     # --- Dish names from dish.model
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GuestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['dish'].queryset = Dish.objects.all()


    def save(self):
        # --- save first Meal.model
        data = self.cleaned_data
        mealData = Meal(table=data['table_input'], dish=data['dish'])
        mealData.save()

        # --- take the meal.pk for guest.meal_id
        meal_id = mealData.id

        # --- save Guest.model
        guestData = Guest(name=data['name'], meal_id=data['meal_id'])
        guestData.save()
```

> **PROBLEM**

`Dish.model` is a list of dishes (Pizza, Hot Dog, Cake...)

`Meal.model` saves the related dish and also adds a Table Number

`Guest.model` relates to a dish and the table number and also adds a guest name. I am using a ManyToMany Relation just for training purpose.

i have template where i can enter every value. If i enter all Values it saves the dish and table number in my database, but not the guest name and ManyToMany relation . On top a Error Message appears and relates to a `KeyError 'meal_id'` in my forms.py (after line: `# --- save Guest.model`).

So the Problem is i need to save the `Meal.model` at first. So i can take the Primary Key of the `Meal.model` and put in the Join Table or the Datafield `Guest.meal`. The Problem is i don´t really understand how this works. So i took the Approach like `Guest.meal` would be a Foreign Key DataField and added `_id`. But `Guest.meal` relates to a Join Table and the the Django Doc (Database Representatio) points it out.

So my question is: how can i make the connection between `Guest.model` and the `Meal.model`? I guess also that in a ManyToMany Relation i need to save both `Guest.id` + `Meal.id` in the DataField `Guest.meal`?

> **Update**

thanks to @dirkgroten

- first i changed the naming of one DataField - `Guest.meal` into `Guest.meals` of my model.
- then i associate both models by using the `.add` method in my form

> updated forms.py

```
class GuestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    dish = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None)

    # --- Input for meal.table
    table_input = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Guest
        fields = [ 
            'name',
            'dish',
            'table_input'
            ]


     # --- Dish names from dish.model
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GuestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['dish'].queryset = Dish.objects.all()


    def save(self):
        # --- save the new Meal.object
        data = self.cleaned_data
        mealData = Meal(table=data['table_input'], dish=data['dish'])
        mealData.save()

        # --- save the new Guest.object 
        guestData = Guest(name=data['name'])
        guestData.save()

        # --- add a m2m relation between Guest.object and Meal.object
        guestData.meals.add(mealData)
        guestData.save()

        return guestData
```

Comment: Have you read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)? You'll learn that `guest.meal.add(some_meal)` creates the relationship between the `guest` and the `some_meal` objects. Don't use ids. By the way, bad naming, use `meals` for your m2m field instead of `meal`, it should be plural.

Comment: @dirkgroten hey dirk first of all thank you. I changed the form as you recommended and it works. I also added a `return` otherwise django (CreateView) would not get the success_url due to the validation i guess.